# Is it possible to update the available browsers in VS2005 load tests

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Is there any way to update the available browsers in a load test in VS2005? By default the most recent is IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under \Common7\IDE\Templates\LoadTest\Browser you will find a bunch of .browser files.  You can add to the list of browsers by createing a new .browser file with the appropriate useragent entries.  You might be able to copy the ones from 2010 back to 2008, but I haven't tried it.